# QtConcurrent::map() with member function = can not compile

Tags: multithreading, qt, qtconcurrent

My project is to create a small program which demonstrates the work of a search engine: indexing and returning result for arbitrary queries. I've done the work with the indexer part and now I want to improve it with indexing multiple files at once. The MainWindow class is here:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    .....
private:
    Indexer * indexer;
    QStringList fileList;
    ....
    void index(QStringList list);
    void add(const QString &filename);
}
```

This is the implementation of `add` (`add` need to access `fileList` to avoid index the same files again, thus it can not be static method):

```
void MainWindow::add(const QString &filename)
{
    if (!fileList.contains(filename))
    {
        indexer->addDocument(filename.toStdString());
        fileList.append(filename);
        qDebug() << "Indexed" << filename;
        emit updatedList(fileList);
    }
}
```

The implement of `index` method is to receive a file lists and call `add` upon each file name:

```
void MainWindow::index(QStringList list)
{
    ....
    QtConcurrent::map(list, &MainWindow::add);
    ....
}
```

The error I receive when compiling these code is:

```
usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qtconcurrentmapkernel.h: In member function 'bool QtConcurrent::MapKernel<Iterator, MapFunctor>::runIteration(Iterator, int, void*) [with Iterator = QList<QString>::iterator, MapFunctor = QtConcurrent::MemberFunctionWrapper1<void, MainWindow, const QString&>]':
../search-engine/mainwindow.cpp:361:1:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qtconcurrentmapkernel.h:73:9: error: no match for call to '(QtConcurrent::MemberFunctionWrapper1<void, MainWindow, const QString&>) (QString&)'
/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qtconcurrentfunctionwrappers.h:128:7: note: candidate is:
/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qtconcurrentfunctionwrappers.h:138:14: note: T QtConcurrent::MemberFunctionWrapper1<T, C, U>::operator()(C&, U) [with T = void, C = MainWindow, U = const QString&]
/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qtconcurrentfunctionwrappers.h:138:14: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
```

I'm not really familiar with how QtConcurrent works, and the documentation doesn't provide much details about it. I really hope that someone here can help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To be able to call a pointer-to-member, you need, in addition to that functions formal arguments, an instance of that class (the `this` pointer that you get inside member functions).

There are two ways to handle this: create a simple functor to wrap the call, or use a lambda.

The functor would look like this:

```
struct AddWrapper {
  MainWindow *instance;
  AddWrapper(MainWindow *w): instance(w) {}
  void operator()(QString const& data) {
    instance->add(data);
  }
};
```

And you'd use it like:

```
AddWrapper wrap(this);
QtConcurrent::map(list, wrap);
```

(Careful with the lifetime of that wrapper though. You could make that more generic - you could also store a pointer-to-member in the wrapper for instance, and/or make it a template if you want to reuse that structure for other types.)

If you have a C++11 compiler with lambdas, you can avoid all that boilerpalte:

```
QtConcurrent::map(list, [this] (QString const& data) { add(data); });
```

---

Note: I'm not sure how `QtConcurrent::MemberFunctionWrapper1` got involved in your example, I'm not seeing it here. So there might be a generic wrapper already in Qt for this situation, but I'm not aware of it.

Comment: The `Indexer` class is actually an AVL tree class. After some research I've realized that my implementation doesn't support concurrent operations on the tree. What I really need is an Relax-Balanced AVL tree instead.

Comment: I don't really see how that relates to the specific problem you posted about.

Comment: For my specific problem, your solution is right. I can happily compile my code with the lambdas. Though I can not test it because my program got seg fault with the function.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I thought I might have missed your point. I'm afraid I don't know much about concurrent tree structures though, sorry.