# Qt::Concurrent mapped with a member function

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qtconcurrent

I want to use the `QtConcurrent::mapped()` function, but going through the [QtConcurrent examples](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentexamples.html) provided and trying to find a usable example to extend to my use has been difficult.

In the examples, Qt [maps](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/examples/qtconcurrent/map/main.cpp?h=5.15#n79) to static functions only, no member functions are used (many simliar mapped variations are found in the examples, but no member functions are used).

**The problem:**

`QtConcurrent::map()` applies a function to a Sequence or Iterator w/o returning i.e. `QFuture<void>`. However I wish to have the results returned i.e. `QFuture<SomeStructOrType>` from a member function.

The example/scenario I want to use it in is an intensive workload in a UI application, but a simplied example could be:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
     Q_OBJECT

  public:
     // The struct is to demonstrate a datatype more complex than int / QString
     struct IntStruct {
         int i;
     };

     MainWindow(QWidget* parent = nullptr);
     IntStruct doubleValue(IntStruct i);
     ~MainWindow();

private:
   Ui::MainWindow* ui;
   // To watch progress and act upon progress change
   QFutureWatcher<IntStruct> futureWatcher;

   // Member to keep track of mapped process
   QFuture<IntStruct> future;

   //...
}
```

The implementation being:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent)
     : QMainWindow(parent)
     , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
     ui->setupUi(this);

     // Input Sequence/Iterator to perform doubleValue function on
     QList<IntStruct> intList = QList<IntStruct>();
     for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
         IntStruct s;
         s.i = qrand();
         intList.append(s);
     }

     // Watch future and report on result ready (process a result when done)
     connect(&futureWatcher, &QFutureWatcher<IntStruct>::resultReadyAt, this, [intList](int index){
         qDebug() << QString("[index = %1] value = %2").arg(QString::number(index), QString::number(intList.at(index).i));
     });

     //typedef IntStruct (MainWindow::*doubleValueFunction)(IntStruct);
     //doubleValueFunction memberFunction = this->doubleValue;             // this->doubleValue error: reference to non-static member function must be called ???

     // Run future - this doubleValue function should be a pointer to an instance function, how to do so?         
     future = QtConcurrent::mapped(intList, &MainWindow::doubleValue);
     futureWatcher.setFuture(future);
}

// Some complex member function
MainWindow::IntStruct MainWindow::doubleValue(MainWindow::IntStruct i)
{
    i.i *= i.i;
    return i;
}
```

I am aware that QtConcurrent allows lambdas, however I need to utilize a member function instead.

I also attempted using a pointer to the current instance with a lambda, but it gave my a schpiel of errors, which you can find [here](https://pastebin.com/MQsA6YMr).

```
 future = QtConcurrent::mapped(intList, [this](IntStruct &i){
     this->doubleValue(i);
 });
```

**TL;DR**
So basically, how can I use [QtConcurrent::mapped(](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent.html#mapped)) with a member function (in preferably a non-lambda version)?

---

**UPDATE for Bounty question**

Some extra information:

This is shown on screen

[image]

Error log when I try to compile:

```
..\ThreadTester\mainwindow.cpp: In constructor 'MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)':
..\ThreadTester\mainwindow.cpp:27:69: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'QFuture<MainWindow::IntStruct>' and 'QFuture<void>')
      future = QtConcurrent::mapped(intList, &MainWindow::doubleValue);
                                                                     ^
In file included from F:\Qt\Qt5.13.1\5.13.1\mingw73_32\include\QtCore/QFuture:1:0,
                 from ..\ThreadTester\thread.h:10,
                 from ..\ThreadTester\mainwindow.h:6,
                 from ..\ThreadTester\mainwindow.cpp:1:
F:\Qt\Qt5.13.1\5.13.1\mingw73_32\include\QtCore/qfuture.h:59:7: note: candidate: QFuture<MainWindow::IntStruct>& QFuture<MainWindow::IntStruct>::operator=(const QFuture<MainWindow::IntStruct>&)
 class QFuture
       ^~~~~~~
F:\Qt\Qt5.13.1\5.13.1\mingw73_32\include\QtCore/qfuture.h:59:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'QFuture<void>' to 'const QFuture<MainWindow::IntStruct>&'
F:\Qt\Qt5.13.1\5.13.1\mingw73_32\include\QtCore/qfuture.h:59:7: note: candidate: QFuture<MainWindow::IntStruct>& QFuture<MainWindow::IntStruct>::operator=(QFuture<MainWindow::IntStruct>&&)
F:\Qt\Qt5.13.1\5.13.1\mingw73_32\include\QtCore/qfuture.h:59:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'QFuture<void>' to 'QFuture<MainWindow::IntStruct>&&'
In file included from F:\Qt\Qt5.13.1\5.13.1\mingw73_32\include/QtConcurrent/qtconcurrentfilterkernel.h:48:0,
                 from F:\Qt\Qt5.13.1\5.13.1\mingw73_32\include\QtConcurrent/qtconcurrentfilter.h:47,
                 from F:\Qt\Qt5.13.1\5.13.1\mingw73_32\include\QtConcurrent/QtConcurrent:8,
                 from ..\ThreadTester\thread.h:11,
                 from ..\ThreadTester\mainwindow.h:6,
                 from ..\ThreadTester\mainwindow.cpp:1:
F:\Qt\Qt5.13.1\5.13.1\mingw73_32\include/QtConcurrent/qtconcurrentmapkernel.h: In instantiation of 'QtConcurrent::ThreadEngineStarter<T> QtConcurrent::startMapped(const Sequence&, Functor) [with T = void; Sequence = QList<MainWindow::IntStruct>; Functor = QtConcurrent::MemberFunctionWrapper1<MainWindow::IntStruct, MainWindow, MainWindow::IntStruct>]':
F:\Qt\Qt5.13.1\5.13.1\mingw73_32\include\QtConcurrent/qtconcurrentmap.h:132:88:   required from 'QFuture<typename QtPrivate::MapResultType<void, MapFunctor>::ResultType> QtConcurrent::mapped(const Sequence&, MapFunctor) [with Sequence = QList<MainWindow::IntStruct>; MapFunctor = MainWindow::IntStruct (MainWindow::*)(MainWindow::IntStruct); typename QtPrivate::MapResultType<void, MapFunctor>::ResultType = void]'
..\ThreadTester\mainwindow.cpp:27:69:   required from here
F:\Qt\Qt5.13.1\5.13.1\mingw73_32\include/QtConcurrent/qtconcurrentmapkernel.h:237:71: error: could not convert 'QtConcurrent::startThreadEngine(ThreadEngine*) [with ThreadEngine = QtConcurrent::SequenceHolder1<QList<MainWindow::IntStruct>, QtConcurrent::MappedEachKernel<QList<MainWindow::IntStruct>::const_iterator, QtConcurrent::MemberFunctionWrapper1<MainWindow::IntStruct, MainWindow, MainWindow::IntStruct> >, QtConcurrent::MemberFunctionWrapper1<MainWindow::IntStruct, MainWindow, MainWindow::IntStruct> >; typename ThreadEngine::ResultType = MainWindow::IntStruct]()' from 'QtConcurrent::ThreadEngineStarter<MainWindow::IntStruct>' to 'QtConcurrent::ThreadEngineStarter<void>'
     return startThreadEngine(new SequenceHolderType(sequence, functor));
                                                                       ^
F:\Qt\Qt5.13.1\5.13.1\mingw73_32\include/QtConcurrent/qtconcurrentmapkernel.h: In instantiation of 'bool QtConcurrent::MappedEachKernel<Iterator, MapFunctor>::runIteration(Iterator, int, QtConcurrent::MappedEachKernel<Iterator, MapFunctor>::T*) [with Iterator = QList<MainWindow::IntStruct>::const_iterator; MapFunctor = QtConcurrent::MemberFunctionWrapper1<MainWindow::IntStruct, MainWindow, MainWindow::IntStruct>; QtConcurrent::MappedEachKernel<Iterator, MapFunctor>::T = MainWindow::IntStruct]':
..\ThreadTester\mainwindow.cpp:36:1:   required from here
F:\Qt\Qt5.13.1\5.13.1\mingw73_32\include/QtConcurrent/qtconcurrentmapkernel.h:175:17: error: no match for call to '(QtConcurrent::MemberFunctionWrapper1<MainWindow::IntStruct, MainWindow, MainWindow::IntStruct>) (const MainWindow::IntStruct&)'
         *result = map(*it);
In file included from F:\Qt\Qt5.13.1\5.13.1\mingw73_32\include\QtConcurrent/qtconcurrentfilter.h:48:0,
                 from F:\Qt\Qt5.13.1\5.13.1\mingw73_32\include\QtConcurrent/QtConcurrent:8,
                 from ..\ThreadTester\thread.h:11,
                 from ..\ThreadTester\mainwindow.h:6,
                 from ..\ThreadTester\mainwindow.cpp:1:
F:\Qt\Qt5.13.1\5.13.1\mingw73_32\include/QtConcurrent/qtconcurrentfunctionwrappers.h:132:14: note: candidate: T QtConcurrent::MemberFunctionWrapper1<T, C, U>::operator()(C&, U) [with T = MainWindow::IntStruct; C = MainWindow; U = MainWindow::IntStruct]
     inline T operator()(C &c, U u)
              ^~~~~~~~
F:\Qt\Qt5.13.1\5.13.1\mingw73_32\include/QtConcurrent/qtconcurrentfunctionwrappers.h:132:14: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
mingw32-make[1]: *** [Makefile.Debug:1117: debug/mainwindow.o] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/CybeX/QtProjects/build-ThreadTester-Desktop_Qt_5_13_1_MinGW_32_bit-Debug'
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:38: debug] Error 2
```

What does not make sense to me at all is `mapped()` returns some datatype U. If I changed the `QFuture<IntStruct>` to `QFuture<void>`, everyone is happy, but I cannot gather any results which defeats the purpose of the `mapped()` function in the first place.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361044/qtconcurrentmap-with-member-function-can-not-compile

Comment: @Kieran I looked through it, used this with `map()` and it works, but with `mapped()` it is a different story. `map()` allows a `QFuture<void>`, but mapped requires a `result_type` which is in line with where my problem lies.

Comment: It seems like the member function pointer to a function taking an instance pointer, and a QFuture<IntStruct> should work for this. What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: something lilke ``MainWindow::IntStruct MainWindow::doubleValue(MainWindow* instance, intstruct data)
{
    return instance->doublevalue(data)
}

Comment: @Kieran not entirely sure if the lowercase v for doublevalue was intended, if it was not, then you have a stackoverflow on your hands. If it is intended, I can just aswel use a wrapper, however I would like to eliminate the need for a wrapper.

Comment: That was something I typed quickly as semi psuedo code so I apologize for any mistakes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

```cpp
#include <functional>

# ....

future = QtConcurrent::mapped(intList,
                              std::bind(&MainWindow::doubleValue,
                                        this,
                                        std::placeholders::_1));
```